# Linear term in string mode expansion

Tags: waves, string-theory, fourier-transform, boundary-conditions

From wave equation upon quantising a string:
$$ \partial^2_\tau X-\partial^2_\sigma X^2=0,$$ obtain that the solution looks like this $$X^\mu=X_L(\tau+\sigma)+X_R(\tau-\sigma).$$ Then fourier expansion gives $$X^\mu_{L/R}=x^\mu_{L/R}+\frac{1}{2}\alpha'p^\mu(\tau\pm\sigma)+i\sqrt{\frac{\alpha'}{2}}\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{a^\mu_{n,L/R}}{n}e^{-in(\tau\pm\sigma)}.$$
I would like to understand where does the linear term in the expression containing $(\tau\pm\sigma)$ come from. I don't think such term appear explicitly in the fourier expansion of any function, although I do see that such a term is necessary so that this expression is compatible with the conserved charge we get from noether's theorem (i.e. string action symmetry is there before we write down such an expression).

Of course we could expand each Fourier mode exponential function and there will be linear terms, does this mean we somehow extracted this $(\tau\pm\sigma)$ piece from these linear terms? But then how can we still write down all these Fourier modes as if they are intact?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454080/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just imagine you were solving the classical equation of motion. You would want a sum of all solutions with constants that you would use to fit the initial conditions. Now  any function of $\tau\pm \sigma$   solves the wave equation --- including the linear term.  So, so long as a long as it satisfies the boundary conditions,  you should include it.   You usually only have the exponentials when you have ordinary periodic boundary conditions,  but the string BC's are not the same as conventional periodic BC.s

For what it is worth, you can find my personal take on the chiral boson [here](http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/zero-modes.pdf).